# How to load a url which is in entry widget of tkinter which is linked with saved user input of a list in list-box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

**My Problem is described in these following steps:**
1. Opened Application 
2. Typed name = Mike ; id = 11 ; url = www.google.com 
3. Clicked on "Add" 
4. Closed the application. 
5. Again Run the application. 
6. Shows "Mike = 11" in the list box. 
7. But when I select "Mike = 11" and click on "load" , it does not take me to "www.google.com", Why? 
**Please give me some solutions about how can I open a URL attaching with saved list.**
**Please HELP me!!**

[image: screenshot of ERROR]

```
from tkinter import*
import webbrowser

def add():
    name = entry1.get()
    id = entry2.get()
    listbox.insert(END, name+ " : " +id)

def delete():
    select = listbox.curselection()
    index = select[0]
    listbox.delete(index)

def save():
    with open("file.txt","w") as f:
        for i in listbox.get(0,END):
            f.write(i+"\n")
            #f.close()

def load():
    url = entry3.get()
    select=listbox.curselection()
    index=select[0]
    webbrowser.open(index)

read = open("file.txt","r")
data_list = read.readlines()
read.close()
data_list = [data.rstrip() for data in data_list]

win = Tk()
win.title("Class")

frame1=Frame(win)
frame2=Frame(win)
frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()

label1 = Label(frame1,text="Name : ")
label1.grid(row=0,column=0)

label2 = Label(frame1,text="Id : ")
label2.grid(row=1,column=0)

label3 = Label(frame1,text="Url : ")
label3.grid(row=2,column=0)

name = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(frame1,textvariable=name)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=1)

id = StringVar()
entry2 = Entry(frame1,textvariable=id)
entry2.grid(row=1,column=1)

url = StringVar()
entry3 = Entry(frame1,textvariable=url)
entry3.grid(row=2,column=1)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame2,orient=VERTICAL)

listbox = Listbox(frame2,selectmode=EXTENDED,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,width=60)
listbox.pack()

scrollbar.config(command=listbox)

for item in data_list:
    listbox.insert(END,item)

button1 = Button(frame2,text="Add",command=add)
button1.pack()

button2 = Button(frame2,text="Delete",command=delete)
button2.pack()

button3 = Button(frame2,text="Save to File",command=save)
button3.pack()

button4 = Button(frame2,text="Load Url",command=load)
button4.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you put urls in the file and in listbox also?

Comment: Your url didn't save in your file.delete `f.close()` in the function `save()`(No need to use `f.close()` after use `with open(xxx)`,it will close this file IO automatically).

Comment: @DevanshSoni I just want listbox to show name and id. And, whenever I click on it, it should generate it's url. If there is any another method that I can perform, please notify me.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Can I save url in my file and also not show in listbox?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA yes i removed `f.close()` but still it does not generate the url.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I see. Thank you so much for solving :) Really appreciate your time!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two list.one list saves `data` in the file,this could be seen in the `Listbox`.The another list is to save the `url` in the file.this couldn't be seen.And also you need to synchronize them.(`save()`,`delete()`,`add()` need to operate both `Listbox` widget and the `list`).A minimal example.:

```
from tkinter import*
import webbrowser

def add():
    name = entry1.get()
    id = entry2.get()
    url = entry3.get()
    url_list.append(url)
    listbox.insert(END, name+ " : " +id)

def delete():
    select = listbox.curselection()
    index = select[0]
    url_list.pop(index)
    listbox.delete(index)

def save():
    with open("file.txt","w") as f:
        for i,j in zip(listbox.get(0,END),url_list):
            f.write(f"{i}  Url:{j}\n")

def load():
    select=listbox.curselection()
    index=select[0]
    load_url = url_list[index]
    webbrowser.open(load_url)

read = open("file.txt","r")
data_url_list = read.readlines()
read.close()
data_list = [data.rstrip().split("Url")[0] for data in data_url_list]
url_list = [data.rstrip().split("Url:")[1] for data in data_url_list]
win = Tk()
win.title("Class")

frame1=Frame(win)
frame2=Frame(win)
frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()

label1 = Label(frame1,text="Name : ")
label1.grid(row=0,column=0)

label2 = Label(frame1,text="Id : ")
label2.grid(row=1,column=0)

label3 = Label(frame1,text="Url : ")
label3.grid(row=2,column=0)

name = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(frame1,textvariable=name)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=1)

id = StringVar()
entry2 = Entry(frame1,textvariable=id)
entry2.grid(row=1,column=1)

url = StringVar()
entry3 = Entry(frame1,textvariable=url)
entry3.grid(row=2,column=1)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame2,orient=VERTICAL)

listbox = Listbox(frame2,selectmode=EXTENDED,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,width=60)
listbox.pack()

scrollbar.config(command=listbox)

for item in data_list:
    listbox.insert(END,item)

button1 = Button(frame2,text="Add",command=add)
button1.pack()

button2 = Button(frame2,text="Delete",command=delete)
button2.pack()

button3 = Button(frame2,text="Save to File",command=save)
button3.pack()

button4 = Button(frame2,text="Load Url",command=load)
button4.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

In this example,the format in the file:

```
name : id  Url:xxxxxx
```

You also could use another way to save them and read them.